# Upgrade Windows XP SP2 to SP3

Tags: windows-xp, upgrade, sp3, sp2

How do I upgrade Windows XP SP2 to Service Pack 3?

Comment: Can somebody fix the English up?

Comment: @Hello: I tried, hope it's better now.

Comment: Much better. :)

Answer (score 10):

Run [Windows Update](http://update.microsoft.com), or download the [standalone installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=68c48dad-bc34-40be-8d85-6bb4f56f5110).

Comment: With Windows Update being set to automatic updates *by default* it's seriously shocking to see someone unable to figure out how to get SP 3 ... (and that's *two years* after it was released)

Comment: I'm just shocked to see people still clinging to XP like it's their mother.